# How to check for TR1 while compiling?

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map, tr1

We are programming a logging library that keeps itself in a .hpp file. We would like to include `<tr1/unordered_map>` (if the compiler supports TR1,) or the standard `<map>` otherwise. Is there a standard way of checking at compile time if tr1 is available or not?

I was thinking that the same way that the "`__cplusplus`" define symbol is present, there could have been defined a "`__cxx__tr1`" or something like that. I haven't seen that in the drafts for TR1, so I assume it is not present, but I wanted to ask first just in case.

As a note, if those defines don't exist, it wouldn't be a bad idea to include them in proposals themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using any configuration tools like autotools you may try to write a test like:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER(tr1/unordered_map,[AC_DEFINE([HAVE_TR1],[],["Have tr1"])],[])
AC_CHECK_HEADER(unordered_map,[AC_DEFINE([HAVE_CXX0X],[],["Have C++0x"])],[])
```

And then use these defines in your code.

Generally speaking `__cplusplus` macro should give you standard version number, but there is no compiler that gives you 100% standard implementation... Thus write configure macros.

Unfortunately this is only quite reliable way to check such things unless you want to write 1001 `#ifdef` for each compiler (what boost does)

And then:

```
#include "config.h"
#ifdef  HAVE_CXX0X
#  include <unordered_map>
   typedef std::unordered_map<foo,bar> my_map;
#elif HAVE_TR1
#  include <tr1/unordered_map>
   typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<foo,bar> my_map;
#else
#  include <map>
   typedef std::map<foo,bar> my_map;
#endif
```

Comment: OK, that was an option I wanted to avoid, as I want just to release a .hpp file and run. For these "almost standard" things, I would prefer a simple comparison rather than having to run a full-fledged configure.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it seems there is no way, and this seems to be the better way...

Answer (score 2):

GCC-4.3 has:

```
#define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ 1
```

But, this is obviously not standard.

Comment: This macro is defined if you use g++ -std=c++0x and then you have unordered_map in std::unordered_map. Otherwise (no -std=c++0x) you do not have this define but you still can use <tr1/unordered_map> include and std::tr1::unordered_map class.

Comment: Yes, but as others have pointed out, this is something that can only be tested for during configure. All other versions of GCC prior to 4.3 throw an error when that -std switch is given.

Answer (score 2):

See ISO C++ (WG21) paper [N1575](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1575.html). This paper has been dropped from TR1, with no replacement. So there is no official way to detect TR1.

Answer (score 1):

One library I deal with needs to use some classes that got added to TR1 from Boost, preferring TR1 if available.  The solution (being a Unix-based library) is to shove the checks into the configure script.

So in other words, no, nothing portable that I know of.  That said, if you're on Unix, the configure script checks work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one is using VS2010, or any suite that has TR1 available, what would happen if one were to do

```
#include "boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp"
...
std::tr1::unordered_map< ... > uMap;
```

What would be the type of `uMap` be?