# Pythonic alternative to C++ configure macros?

Tags: c++, python, macros, swig, autoconf

I'm looking for a way to do simple build environment checking for my Python project without having to rely on autoconf-style macros. Specifically, I'm porting native C++ classes which use the new `unordered_map` type by wrapping them with SWIG. In the C++-only project, we used autotools/configure macros in the manner described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724465/how-to-check-for-tr1-while-compiling) to check whether the compiler supports `std::unordered_map` or `std::tr1::unordered_map`. The macros all boil down to trying to compile small C++ programs with both options and seeing which one compiles successfully.

Is there a way to do this type of environment checking with setuptools? I tried looking at the setup.py scripts for numpy and matplotlib and it's not clear how they dynamically derive the configuration for the local compilation environment. Should I just open a subprocess in my setup.py script that runs the `./configure` script?

Comment: I would keep the autotools build system, and invoke `python setup.py` from there if needed. What most (if not all) "alternatives" to autotools have in common is they lack basic functionality provided by autotools.

Comment: @DanielKO I hear ya. Ideally I'd like to get my project to where it can be listed as a dependency in someone else's setup.py or installed using `pip install` ... can that still be done when ./configure and not setup.py is the conductor of the orchestra?